# I cant open dropbox

Tags: dropbox

i am install dropbox on ubuntu software center but i cant open dropbox. I see this error

[image]

How can ı fixed that problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by running the command

```
sudo http_proxy=http://your_proxy:proxy_port dropbox start -i
```

or

```
sudo https_proxy=http://your_proxy:proxy_port dropbox start -i
```

Replace http://your_proxy:proxy_port with your proxy and port

Comment: how can learn proxy and port?